# how can I handle variables reacts as variable - property?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to organize my code order to handle `feed` as `feed.*` based on my endpoint API, but however react doesn't allow me to directly send functions into component, but I want something similar to `feed.results, feed. count`

```
const [initialized, setIntialized] = useState(false);  
const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
const browserFeed = async () => {  
    const response = await browse();
    setFeed(response.results);  
    setIntialized(true);  
};

useEffect(() => {  
    if (!initialized) {  
    browserFeed();  
    }  
}); 


export const browse = () =>  {
    return api.get('xxxxxxxx')
    .then(function(response){
      return response.data // returns .count , .next, .previous, and .results
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  <div className="searched-jobs">
  <div className="searched-bar">
    <div className="searched-show">Showing {feed.count}</div>
    <div className="searched-sort">Sort by: <span className="post-time">Newest Post </span><span className="menu-icon">▼</span></div>
  </div>
  <div className="job-overview">
    <div className="job-overview-cards">
      <FeedsList feeds={feed} />
      <div class="job-card-buttons">
        <button class="search-buttons card-buttons-msg">Back</button>
        <button class="search-buttons card-buttons">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to call browse with a different url each time. Not sure I understood the problem.

Comment: exactly, but at the moment to set as `api.get(response.next)` doesnt update in browser

Comment: Is the goal here that you fetch every page of feed. And when you click on next to fetch page 2, 3, 4? Basicly pagination, and you want the url to be url.com/feed?page=5 ?

Comment: exactly as that

Answer (score 0):

If it is pagination you are trying to handle here is one solution:

```
async function fetchFeed(page) {
  return api.get(`https://example.com/feed?page=${page}`);
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);

  // Fetch on first render
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFeed(1).then((data) => setFeed(data));
  }, []);

  // Update feed if the user changes the page
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFeed(currentPage).then((data) => setFeed(data));
  }, [currentPage]);

  const isFirstPage = currentPage === 1;

  return (
    <>
      <FeedsList feeds={feed} />
      {isFirstPage && (
        <button onClick={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)}>Back</button>
      )}
      <button Click={() => setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)}>Next</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: how do I send back `data` to feedlist component {feed} ?

Comment: We are currently sending `data` to `FeedsList`. If you see innside the `useEffect` we are fetching the feed, then calling `setFeed` to add that data into the state `feed`. We are then passing on the `feed`(exactly the same as data) and passing it to feedlist: `<FeedsList feeds={feed} />` Not sure if you want something else?